# Laravel getRouteKeyName replace white space to dash

Tags: laravel, routes

i looking for the url become 127.0.0.1:8000/news/some-article-title. Working on Laravel 5.8

current it show 127.0.0.1:8000/news/some%20article%20title.

I tried few ways to do it...

**First**
Reading the laravel documentation , i found to show title instead of id behind the url.

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
  return 'title';
}
```

**Second**
app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
  parent::boot();

  Route::bind('news', function($value){
     return  \App\Models\News::where('title', str_replace('-', ' ', $value))->first();
  })
}
```

Didn't work. The Url still remain **%20 instead of dash**

Did i miss something important?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the reverse operation like this:

```
 <a href="{{str_replace(' ','-',$new->title)}}"> {{$new->title}}</a>
```

```
 Route::bind('news', function($value){
     return  \App\Models\News::where('title', str_replace(' ', '-', $value))->first();
  })
```

or you need to create specific column like `slug` which will have the same value of title but without spaces

Comment: I using the first solution you provided. It link to 404...The url was replace to dash. But route doesn't correct. The solution 2 (slug) is it created one more column in database?

Comment: yes just create column called `slug` and when you save it you need to save it like this
`str_slug($new->title)` and in blade file make it ike this
`<a href="{{url('/'.$new->slug)}}"> {{$new->title}}</a>`

Comment: in your model

`public function getRouteKeyName()
{
  return 'slug';
}
`

Comment: after that comment route binding in your `RouteServiceProvider`

Comment: \App\Models\News::where('title', str_replace(' ', '-', $value))->first(); Why it using where method to get the collection? i quite don't understand for this =(